# Database schema quality gate / analysis

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sonarqube, schema

I have been given the task to completely revamp a database. This database has all this sort of bad practices, very few Primary keys, missing relationships, poorly selected data types. I appreciate some of these are hard to pick up, but surely there are some tells. if the name is IsActive and the type is nvarchar, this should at least be a code smell. I tried to find quality gates or even some tools like RedGate Schema compare or similar.

Just to finalize this is a SQL Server database, that I am obviously moving into SSDT so we can have historical info about the changes, and I figured that as part of our CI process I would run a quality gate on it.

For instance there is one for T-SQL, https://www.sonarsource.com/tsql/ but I could not find one that would analyse the schema nor really how to set it up either locally or from a bitbucket pipeline perspective

Comment: What exactly is the question? Asking for off-site resources is off-topic. [ask] [help]

Comment: In this forum you can ask things like _how can I query the data schema to return the tables that have columns matching a name and data type_ So we can help you to develop a tool like what you are asking for, but in general your question is vague and will attract opinionated responses. As an example, a large portion of my business is doing exactly the task you have described, if there was a one size fits all approach, I wouldn't have a job.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use [tSQLt unit-testing database framework](https://tsqlt.org/) with lots of generic quality checks. For example searching for tables that have no primary key, or columns that have "id" in the name but do not reference anything, or to enforce naming standards.

It is especially valuable approach if

- you write the tests to also generate the code to fix the issue,
- you have other databases where you can move these tests later within minutes and it saves you days of work.

There is a bunch of tests like these available for free as [SQLCop](https://github.com/red-gate/SQLCop). I highly recommend to check them out, together with tSQLt.